# making a .lnk with powershell not working

Tags: c#, powershell, system-center

I want my my scvmm add-in to create shortcuts to my vm bakcups automatically.
I use powershell-cmdlets on the host:

```
string command2 = "$shell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell;";
foreach (var vm in VMs)
{
    command2 = command2 + string.Format("${1} = shell.CreateShortcut(\"{0}\\{1}\\{2}.lnk\"); ${1}.TargetPath = \"..\\_VMBackup\\{2}\\{1}\"; ${1}.Save();", backupDir, vm.Name, date);
}
```

this is how I invoke them:

```
PowerShellContext.ExecuteScript<Host>(string.Format("Invoke-SCScriptCommand -Executable \"{0}\" -VMHost (Get-SCVMHost -ID \"{1}\") -CommandParameters \"{2}\" -RunAsynchronously -TimeoutSeconds 360000", PowershellPath, VMs.First(), command2), (vms, error) => { if (error != null) { } else { } });
```

Something seems to be wrong though, because I won't execute properly, even though it works if I try it maually in the shell. Got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a "$" before the "shell" variable in string.Format

Try:

```
command2 = command2 + string.Format("${1} = $shell.CreateShortcut(\"{0}\\{1}\\{2}.lnk\"); ${1}.TargetPath = \"..\\_VMBackup\\{2}\\{1}\"; ${1}.Save();", backupDir, vm.Name, date);
```

Instead of:

```
command2 = command2 + string.Format("${1} = shell.CreateShortcut(\"{0}\\{1}\\{2}.lnk\"); ${1}.TargetPath = \"..\\_VMBackup\\{2}\\{1}\"; ${1}.Save();", backupDir, vm.Name, date);
```

Comment: Hm..

Now I get an error message that an argument after "(" in the line ".. .Save();" was expected.

What exactly is wrong? I tried the powershell script successfully on my desktop - it works.

Why do I get this error from the host?

Comment: ..also it says ")" at "..150112-0859.önl);" is an unexpected token.